# Fixed footer in Angular page with Bootstrap 5 hiding content

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5

I try to make a first simple webpage with Angular and Bootstrap 5.

The page should have a footer, which contains a logo and some text. This footer should always be visible and stick to the bottom of the browser window.

I got to a point where the footer looks pretty ok, but when the page content is long, the footer will hide some of the content and the user cannot scroll down to see all the content.

What I'd like to achieve in this situation, is that the user can scroll and access all the content above the footer. I've tried a lot of things, which I found on the Internet, but nothing worked.

## Relevant parts of the Angular app

`index.html`

```html
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

`app.component.html`

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

The content of the page is displayed in `<router-outlet>`. That's the part which a user should be able to scroll vertically in case the window is not high enough to show everything.

`<app-footer>` is where the footer component is displayed.

#### Footer Component

`footer.component.html`

```html
<footer class="bg-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 ps-3 pt-1">
      <img src="../../assets/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 p-2 text-center">
      Some text...
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

`footer.component.css`

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 76px;
}
```